# How fields are created from properties in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

When you create a property does it automatically create field in the same class ? is it possible to define its the protection level for example every time you create a property it will create a protected field ?

Comment: You mean when you write the code for the property yourself, without the aid of tooling such as shortcuts or tools like Resharper?

Comment: @Wicher yes i mean without shortcuts.

Comment: In that case, no. You would have to write it by yourself.

Comment: when exactly the field is created in witch step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-implemented properties is exactly what you trying to accomplish
From MSDN

> When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the
>   compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be
>   accessed through the property's get and set accessors

```
protected int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

In C#6 you can declare readonly auto-implemented properties

```
protected int MyProperty { get; }
```